# document.execCommand("copy") is failing sometimes and not always

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

I have a function which is invoked on double click event handler. I call below function on dblclick event passing the target text as paremeter texttocopy.

```
copyToClipboard = function (texttocopy) {
    'use strict';
    var answer = confirm(`Do you want to copy into the clipbaord `);
    if (answer == true) {
        let input = document.createElement('textarea');
        input.innerHTML = texttocopy;
        document.body.appendChild(input);
        input.select();
        let result = document.execCommand('copy', false);
        document.body.removeChild(input);
        if (result) return;
        else alert("Failed to copy to clipboard");
    }

}
```

If I press on Ok of the confirm popup in say 2 secs, my code is successful but if I press after 5-10 secs, its failing. My understanding is that document.exeCommand works on short lived user generated event handlers. But I want to understand what actually counts as a "short-lived event,"
Is there a way I can make this successful programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned:

> These commands can be used without any special permission if you are using them in a short-lived event handler for a user action (for example, a click handler). ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard#using_execcommand()))

The problem you're running into is that you're using `confirm`. This dialog breaks the normal flow (it halts operation), which breaks you our of that event handler's scope.

Removing that `confirm` should fix your problem:

```js
copyToClipboard = function (texttocopy) {
    'use strict';
    var answer = true; //confirm(`Do you want to copy into the clipbaord `);
    if (answer == true) {
        let input = document.createElement('textarea');
        input.innerHTML = texttocopy;
        document.body.appendChild(input);
        input.select();
        let result = document.execCommand('copy', false);
        document.body.removeChild(input);
        if (result) return;
        else alert("Failed to copy to clipboard");
    }
}

document.getElementById('copy')
    .addEventListener('click', () => copyToClipboard(
        'Copy this text to the clipboard!'));
```

```html
<button type="button" id="copy">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: But it is still working for  confirm pressed in 1-2 secs, so I do not agree to  reason that it is coming out of scope from eventhandler. My question is what determines a  short lived event.

Comment: I'd guess that depends on the browser. These events are always triggered from a _user interaction_, and they are short-lived for security reasons, as those events come with some extra permissions like copy-pasting. The `confirm` makes it very easy for your code to let the event expire, maybe "scope" isn't the right word here. If you _need_  a confirmation dialog, you're going to have to build a dialog that triggers the copy action when the user clicks your custom dialog's "ok" button.

Comment: Is there a way I can check document.execCommand natiive code. Its not that I want to not use a custom dialog box but I would like to know what is that in the event property which makes it short lived. I believe isTrusted property of the event is one factor which this api must be checking and I am wondering what other field it could be

Comment: FireFox and Chromium (chrome's engine) are open-source, so you could look into that. I suspect the event has some kind of timer / timestamp, but this is something you can't fake without modding the browser.

Comment: Yes I agree, I dont intend to fake it but would like to know what exactly is short lived event. Do they start a timer and if yes, how long etc. I checked the open source chromium code and its a pain to search exact function there. Am I searching in wrong way